# I want to create an adaptive card with buttons for email and call functionality. Whats the possible way for that?

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

I want to create an adaptive card with buttons for email and call functionality. I cannot find a format for call and email in adaptive cards. Is there a way to combine adaptive cards with hero cards, since hero cards have the cardAction object functionality ?

Comment: Have you checked my answer, any update?

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Cards have action elements and selectactions that can be set. You would create a card with your input requirements and then use a submit action to process the input. Note on the text input elements, the format has been set to either email or tel

```
{"type":"AdaptiveCard","version":"1.0","id":"c2de1dd7-c916-4196-a914-0694957aff77","minVersion":"1.0","fallbackText":"","speak":"","body":[{"type":"TextBlock","id":"23af4d94-cf3b-480e-8c28-5a7988b8a26b","text":"Email Address","maxLines":1},{"type":"Input.Text","id":"4a47c737-dbf0-42d0-aa9f-10f4f38bd20f","placeholder":"enter your email here","value":"","style":"email","maxLength":250,"isRequired":false},{"type":"TextBlock","id":"b4f3bce9-2464-473f-9129-48a3740aec8b","size":"large","text":"OR","horizontalAlignment":"center","maxLines":1},{"type":"TextBlock","id":"fe2d84aa-79e7-4fdf-91a0-79a9eb264dc1","text":"Call me","maxLines":1},{"type":"Input.Text","id":"d03d538f-7ead-4959-8a8e-7703dbaf1899","placeholder":"What's your number?","value":"","style":"tel","maxLength":250,"isRequired":false}],"actions":[{"type":"Action.Submit","id":"8421a872-2c4f-4fa2-8254-b1d88503cc8a","data":"","title":"Email Me"},{"type":"Action.Submit","id":"2ccf2819-ad38-492a-80f9-7cd5152fea09","data":"","title":"Call Me"}]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to combine adaptive cards with hero cards, since hero cards have the cardAction object functionality ?

No, but Buttons within `AdaptiveCard` are not created using `CardAction` objects, you can use schema that is [defined in AdaptiveCard](http://adaptivecards.io/explorer/) instead.

There're three kinds of actions `OpenUrl`, `Submit` and `ShowCard`. Here `Submit` is what we need.

If you want to create `AdaptiveCard` in C#, you can for example create it and send the message like this:

```cs
AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard()
{
    Body = new List<CardElement>()
    {
        new Container()
        {
            Speak = "<s>Hello!</s><s>Send Email!</s>",
            Items = new List<CardElement>()
            {
                new TextBlock()
                {
                     Text = "Hello!",
                     Weight = TextWeight.Bolder,
                     IsSubtle = true
                },
                new TextBlock()
                {
                     Text = "Send Email!",
                     Wrap = true
                },
                new TextInput()
                {
                    Id = "EmailAddTo",
                    Placeholder = "To:"
                },
                new TextInput()
                {
                    Id = "EmailAddFrom",
                    Placeholder = "From:"
                },
                new TextInput()
                {
                    Id = "Subject",
                    Placeholder = "Subject:"
                },
                new TextInput()
                {
                    Id = "Content",
                    Placeholder = "Content:",
                    IsMultiline = true,                          
                }
            }
        }
    },
    Actions = new List<ActionBase>()
    {
        new SubmitAction()
        {
            Title = "Send Email",
            DataJson = "{\"Type\": \"EmailSend\"}"
        }
    }
};

Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
{
    ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
    Content = card
};

var reply = context.MakeMessage();
reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);

await context.PostAsync(reply,CancellationToken.None);
```

When using `Submit` action, the Bot Framework will handle the submission and your bot will receive a new `IMessageActivity` with its `Value`, you can then handle it in your code for example like this:

```cs
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var message = await result;

    if (message.Value != null)
    {
        // Got an Action Submit
        dynamic value = message.Value;
        string submitType = value.Type.ToString();
        switch (submitType)
        {
            case "EmailSend":
                /* */
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, you can refer to the official [Adaptive Cards Bot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-AdaptiveCards).